# Why is the logistic regression hypothesis seen as a probability function?

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model

Why is the logistic regression hypothesis seen as a probability function?

I understand that we use it to predict 0 or 1, but still, why a function (the hypothesis) that outputs numbers between 0 and 1 may be considered a probability function?

Is this a heuristic?

Comment: this post may be helpful. Check the accepted answer. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229645/why-there-are-two-different-logistic-loss-formulation-notations

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not merely a heuristic. It's quite deliberately intended to be a model for the conditional distribution of the response.

[Logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) is a particular case of a [generalized linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) (GLM), in this case for a process where the response variable is conditionally [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) (or more generally, [binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)).

A GLM includes a specification of a model for the conditional mean of the response. In the case of a Bernoulli variable, its conditional mean is the parameter $p_i$, which is explicitly the probability that the response, $Y_i$ is $1$. It is modeled in terms of one or more predictors. Here's the model for the mean for a single predictor, $x_i$:

$$P(Y_i=1|x_i)=\frac{\exp(\beta_0+\beta_1x_i)}{1+\exp(\beta_0+\beta_1x_i)}$$

So it is (intentionally) a model for the *probability* that the response is $1$, given the value of the predictors.

The form of the link function $\eta=\log(p/(1-p))$ (and its inverse $p=\exp(\eta)/(1+\exp(\eta))$) is no accident either -- the logit link (which is what makes it logistic regression) is the *natural* (or *canonical*) link function for a binomial response. Other choices of link function are possible (and they, too will be models for the probability of a 1). Other common choices for a binomial response are the probit and the complementary log-log but the logistic is by far the most common.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but the function should be a proper scoring rule. In such cases it will reflect the probability.

Comment: @Cagdas The criterion being optimized in estimation GLMs is likelihood (though MLE can be seen as a special case of optimal score estimation). Are you casting the modelling of Bernoulli variables as a forecasting problem here?