# The correct loss function for logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, loss-functions

I've been using logistic regression for a specific problem and the loss function the paper used is the following : 
$$ L(Y,\hat{Y})=\sum_{i=1}^{N} \log(1+\exp(-y_i\hat{y}_{i}))$$ 
Yesterday, I came accross Andrew Ng's course (Stanford notes) and he gave another loss function that was intuitive, according to his saying. The function was : 
$$J(\theta)=\frac{−1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}y^{(i)}\log(h_\theta(x^{(i)}))+(1−y^{(i)})\log(1−h_\theta(x^{(i)}))$$
Now I know there isn't only ONE loss function per model and that both could be used.

My question is more about what separates those two functions ? Is there any advantage of working with one instead of the other ? Are they equivalent in any way ?
thanks !

Comment: "[..] the paper used [..]" Could you include a reference to this paper?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the sigmoid function in logistic regression, these two loss functions are totally same, the main difference is that

- $y_i\in\{-1,1\}$ is used in first loss function;
- $y_i\in\{0,1\}$ is used in the second loss function.

Two loss functions can be derived by maximizing likelihood function.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the choice of the labels, and each choice has (arguably) some advantages over the other. You should visit [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250937/which-loss-function-is-correct-for-logistic-regression/279698#279698) for more detailed information on the topic.