# Logistic Regression Cost Function proof by using maximizing likelihood function

Tags: machine-learning, logistic

In  [Andrew Ng's Coursera Machine Learning class](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIQlmHxI6-0&list=PLNeKWBMsAzboR8vvhnlanxCNr2V7ITuxy&index=4) or [Logistic Regression](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/cost-function-logistic-regression).he cost function for logistic regression is defined as:

$$  
J({\theta}) =\frac{1}{m}  \sum_{i=1}^m Cost(h_{\theta}(x^{(i)},y^{(i)})
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
  Cost(h_{\theta}(x),y)=\begin{cases}
    -\log(h_{\theta}(x)), & \text{if $y=1$}.\\
    -\log(1-h_{\theta}(x)), & \text{if $y=0$}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation} 
$$
Then It is said that this simplifies to:

$$
J(\theta) = - \frac{1}{m} \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^m \left[y^{(i)}\log \big(h_\theta (x^{(i)})\big) + (1 - y^{(i)})\log \big(1 - h_\theta(x^{(i)})\big)\right] \\[6pt]
$$

In this [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/logistic-regression-detailed-overview-46c4da4303bc) under why this cost function? she had given the Maximum Likelihood Explanation which I did not understand. even [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286516/the-correct-loss-function-for-logistic-regression?noredirect=1&lq=1), the accepted answer has the last line as **Two loss functions can be derived by maximizing likelihood function.**

Can anyone give me proper mathematical(Maximum Likelihood Explanation) proof of how we arrive 
at the following cost function?

$$
\begin{equation}
  Cost(h_{\theta}(x),y)=\begin{cases}
    -\log(h_{\theta}(x)), & \text{if $y=1$}.\\
    -\log(1-h_{\theta}(x)), & \text{if $y=0$}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation} 
$$

Comment: This is my [blog](https://github.com/AnilSarode/Machine-Learning-Digital-Book-/blob/master/Logistic_Regression/Logistic%20Regression%20or%20Classification.ipynb) on Logistic Regression here you will find the answer in 10.Logistic Regression from Statistical point of view.