# XGBClassifier and XGBRegressor

Tags: metric, boosting

I am a newbie to Xgboost and I would like to use it for regression, in particular, car prices prediction. I started following a tutorial on XGboost which uses XGBClassifier and objective= 'binary:logistic' for classification and even though I am predicting prices, there is an option for objective = 'reg:linear' in XGBClassifier.

1) Should XGBClassifier and XGBRegressor always be used for classification and regression respectively?

2) Why does objective ='reg:linear' option even exist for XGBClassifier?
Shouldn't it be only available in XGBRegressor?

3) Is "explained variance" the best metric for regression model evaluation? or perhaps RMSE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) Should XGBClassifier and XGBRegressor always be used for
>   classification and regression respectively?

Basically yes, but some would argue that [logistic regression is in fact a regression problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127042/why-isnt-logistic-regression-called-logistic-classification/127044#127044), not classification, where we [predict probabilities](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/227009/logistic-regression-how-to-call-the-output/228212#228212). You can call predicting probabilities "soft classification", but this is about a naming convention.

> 2) Why does objective ='reg:linear' option even exist for
>   XGBClassifier? Shouldn't it be only available in XGBRegressor?

Logistic regression uses [logistic loss function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250937/which-loss-function-is-correct-for-logistic-regression), but no one prohibits you from minimizing squared loss, i.e. squared difference between predicted probabilities and the target zeros and ones. As far as I understand from the documentation, this is what XGBoost will do if you use the `'reg:linear'` parameter in here. See also the [What is the difference between linear regression and logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29325/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-regression-and-logistic-regression) thread.

> 3) Is "explained variance" the best metric for regression model
>   evaluation? or perhaps RMSE?

There is no such a thing as "the best metric", if there was, we would be using it for all the problems and didn't have multiple metrics. Metric is problem specific.

Comment: Thanks Tim, so I can use  XGBClassifier for regression problems but it's better to use a dedicated XGBRegressor, right? Is there a big performance difference?

Comment: @Baraban no, you can't. You can use squared loss for classification, you cannot use classifier for regression.