# Ridge classification: Interpreting prediction

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, ridge-regression

I'm particularly concerned about the following problem when using ridge classification for predicting binary outcome

1. When I'm encoding the binary outcome as 1 and 0; my model accuracy is 0.6456
2. When I'm encoding the binary outcome as -1 and 1; my model accuracy is 0.3525

Does anyone know whether the binary outcome in ridge classification is to be made -1 and 1 or 1 and 0 and why?

Any lead is appreciated

Comment: Are you still using a threshold of 0.5 when using -1 and +1 labels (for which the threshold should be 0)?

Comment: Thanks @DikranMarsupial for pointing this out. Indeed this was the label problem

Answer (score 1):

Are use sure that when changing the labels you didn't reverse them? Because both results you got are the same, just the second one got the labels in reverse, $1 - 0.65 = 0.35$.

Both encodings are correct since there are [variations of logistic loss for both cases](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/250937/35989), but which one to choose depends on which your software uses.